# Whatsapp Api Cloud Image Upload Issue

Tags: image, whatsapp, whatsapi

I am trying to upload an image for whataspp cloud api , i've transformed curl code to c# using RestSharp but i got this error . I was triying to change the file parameter format but it doesn't work. I don't know if i am missing something in the json maybe.

here is the code i use :

```
public void whatsapp_image_upload()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://graph.facebook.com/" + num_whatsapp_business + "/media");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token_authorization);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("messaging_product", "whatsapp");
        request.AddParameter("file", "C:\\Users\\cnarea\\Pictures\\empaque.jpg");
        request.AddParameter("type", "image/jpeg");

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    }
```

and this is the error i recieve :

```
{"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"AFWXnEVRuvp82ewjaUEtoLa"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i was able to solve it, i have to use postman app to obtain c# code ,my code is this :

```
 public void whatsapp_image_upload()
    {
        try
        {             
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\cnarea\Pictures\procesos.jpeg";
            var client = new RestClient("https://graph.facebook.com/"+num_whatsapp_business+"/media");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token_authorization);
            request.AddFile("file", filePath, "image/jpeg");
            request.AddParameter("messaging_product", "whatsapp");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

      
    }
```